# wordpress admin plugin page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to write my first plugin for wordpress, is something small that I need for a project.
What this plugin has to do is to change the time of the post with an amount of hours that you have to set on the plugin admin page.
For example if I set the amount of hours at 5 every time I post in a certain category the post should appear as I post it 5 hours before.

I've created the admin page, but what I want to do is to store the hours in the database and set the post time minus the hours.

the plugin code so far is this:

```
    if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

define( 'PLUGIN_NAME_VERSION', '1.0.0' );

/**
 * The code that runs during plugin activation.
 * This action is documented in includes/class-post-time-changer-activator.php
 */
function activate_post_time_changer() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-post-time-changer-activator.php';
    Post_Time_Changer_Activator::activate();
}

/**
 * The code that runs during plugin deactivation.
 * This action is documented in includes/class-post-time-changer-deactivator.php
 */
function deactivate_post_time_changer() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-post-time-changer-deactivator.php';
    Post_Time_Changer_Deactivator::deactivate();
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_post_time_changer' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate_post_time_changer' );

/**
 * The core plugin class that is used to define internationalization,
 * admin-specific hooks, and public-facing site hooks.
 */
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-post-time-changer.php';

/**
 * Begins execution of the plugin.
 *
 * Since everything within the plugin is registered via hooks,
 * then kicking off the plugin from this point in the file does
 * not affect the page life cycle.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
function run_post_time_changer() {

    $plugin = new Post_Time_Changer();
    $plugin->run();

}
run_post_time_changer();


add_action('admin_menu', 'PTC_setup_menu');

function PTC_setup_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 'Post Time Changer', 'PostTimeChanger', 'manage_options', 'post-time-changer', 'ptc_option_page' );
}

function ptc_option_page(){
        ?>
<div class="wrap">
<h1>Post Time Changer</h1>
<form action="options.php" method="post">
<?php settings_fields('plugin_options'); ?>
<?php do_settings_sections('plugin'); ?>

    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes'); ?>" /><br/>
<!-- amount of time the post should be anticipated -->

set the amount of Hours/minutes you want your post to be anticipated <input name="minus" type="number" value="" /><br/>
<?php $minus = $_GET['minus']; ?>
<!--save setting on the bottom -->
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes'); ?>" />
</form></div>
<?php
add_action('admin_init', 'plugin_admin_init');
function plugin_admin_init(){
register_setting( 'plugin_options', 'plugin_options', 'plugin_options_validate' );
add_settings_section('plugin_main', 'Main Settings', 'plugin_section_text', 'plugin');
add_settings_field('plugin_text_string', 'Plugin Text Input', 'plugin_setting_string', 'plugin', 'plugin_main');


}

}
```

and I know that I have to change in the post file the time with this code:

```
<?php $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-6 hours', (int)get_the_time('U'))); echo $date; ?>
```

as you can see in the strtotime is set to -6 hours I want this code di dialog with the plugin and get the time that I've saved in the database.

Anyone can suggest me how to do it?

thank you very much in advance